# Which Star Trek characters have met their own duplicate?

Tags: star-trek

There have been numerous instances in *Star Trek* where characters have been duplicated: by cloning, transporter accidents, holograms, alternate universes, imposters, and so on.  **Which characters have met their own duplicate?**

For the purposes of this question:

- *Star Trek* refers to any of its television series or movies.  So the Animated Series counts, but comic books do not.
- "Met" means being in the same room (or an equivalent proximity).  Seeing each other on viewscreens does not count.  Simultaneously swapping places does not count.
- "Duplicate" is another entity played by the same actor, who could be reasonably be mistaken for the original character.  So Data and Lore count, but Data and Dr. Soong do not count.
- Please identify the episode or movie.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but how will you choose which answer to accept if they can't be comprehensive?

Comment: @Gaultheria: Not all questions necessarily have a "best" answer.  However, you and I and everyone else can upvote good answers.

Comment: The usual format for this kind of question would be for an answer to provide all the cases in one answer.

Comment: Insisting that people limit themselves to a single example is contrary to the state goal of the site to have comprehensive single answers.

Comment: Voted to leave open, but as my two above neighbours pointed out, one example per answer isn't a great format. There are already six answers as of now; reading would be easier in one answer. If you're afraid of some kind of rep-gaming, Community Wiki seems like a good way to go.

Answer (score 3):

William Riker met his transporter duplicate, Thomas Riker (TNG: Season 6 Episode 24, "Second Chances")

Answer (score 3):

Captain Picard meets (and possibly kills) his duplicate in “Time Squared.”

Answer (score 3):

**Janeway**

*Episode 21, season 2 - "Deadlock" (Star Trek": Voyager)*

In fact the whole team of Voyager had their doubles in the episode, but not all of them met each other.

Fun fact: Kim was swapped with his double in the episode, which means in all the future episodes Kim is not the same Kim anymore, but it does not bother anyone.

Comment: Note that Samantha Wildman's child also replaced the baby who died in the duplicate crew.

Comment: Rumor has it that Captain Janeway had plans to promote the "real" Harry Kim. The imposter? Not a chance. He's a permanent ensign, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Does the Doctor from Voyager meeting his creator Dr Zimmerman also count? (Episode "Life Line" of *Star Trek: Voyager*)

Answer (score 1):

In the original series, Captain Kirk was "split" by a transporter malfunction into two versions of himself, which met and conflicted, and eventually merged in "[The Enemy Witin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enemy_Within_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))."

Answer (score 0):

I might as well post the example I put in the question:

Data and his brother Lore (TNG: Datalore, Brothers, Descent part I and II).

Now post your own answer!